# Swagger RestConfiguration, specifying multiple schemes via Java

Tags: apache-camel

Defining Swagger configuration in XML, one can specify multiple schemes, e.g. "http,https". [Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/swagger-java.html)

When using Java configuration, there's only "scheme", not "schemes". I tried passing a comma-delimited string with "http,https", but that does not seem to work.

```
restConfiguration()
  .component('servlet')
  .apiContextPath('api-docs')
  .scheme('https')
```

How does one specify multiple schemes, using Java?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use

Comment: We're using 2.18.0

Comment: Try with newer version. It ought to be able to set `http,https` separated by comma.